# Write $F$ as a linear combination of elements of $\mathcal B^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> If $V=\mathbb R[x]_k=\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^ka_ix^i:a_i\in\mathbb R, \forall i\}$ is a vector space of dimension $k+1$ over $K=\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal B=\{1,x,\dots,x^k\}$ is a basis of $V$. The dual space of $V$ is the vector space $V^*=\{F:V\to K:F\ \text{is linear}\}$ for all $i$;  $x^{i^*}$ is defined as $x^{i^*}(x^j)=\delta_{ij}=\begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if i=j}\\0 & \textrm{else}\end{cases}$, let $\mathcal B^*=\{x^{i^*}:i\in\{0,\dots,k\}\}$ and $F:V\to K$ with $p(x)\mapsto\int_0^1 p(x)$ write $F$ as a linear combination of elements of $\mathcal B^*$

First $\mathcal B^*$ is basis of $V^*$ because $Hom(V,K)\simeq Mat_{1\times(k+1)}(K)$ with $f\mapsto(f(1),\dots f(x^k)$(I can show it is injective and with our chosen $x^{i^*}$ also surjective, and since $x^{i^*}$s are linearly independent it is a basis, but how can I write $F$;

$F=\lambda_01^*+\lambda_1x^*+\dots\lambda_kx^{k^*}$, for examples if $p(x)=x$ then $\int_0^1 p(x)=\frac12$, so $F=\frac12x^*$ and in general $\lambda_k=\frac{1}{k+1}$, am I correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. In general, if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space with basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ v_1, \dots, v_n \}$ and $\mathcal{B}^{*} = \{ \varphi^1, \ldots, \varphi^n \}$ is the corresponding dual basis (so $\varphi^i(v_j) = \delta^i_j$), then given a linear functional $F \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$, we have

$$ F = \sum_{i=1}^n F(v_i) \varphi^i. $$

In your case,

$$ F(x^i) = \int_0^1 x^i \, dx = \frac{1}{i+1} $$ so

$$ F = \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{1}{i+1} \left( x^i \right)^{*}. $$